# Debugging Flash SWF panel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, jsfl, flascc

Does anyone think it could be possible to create a custom debugger for swf files using a socket, able to support breaking points and step through code functionality?

I know there are swf debugger's out there but I have not found one that can step through code...

I was thinking of creating one and would like to get some input and ideas.

I know flash has a System.Pause() function that will stop the player and I can get the code line using stackTrace. but I have no idea how to perform the step functionality.

Maybe FlasCC some how?

Or create a server debugger which will call the pause function every step... but how would I know when a new line is being processed?

The reason I would like to create this is to debug Flash extension SWFpanel which wont connect to flash remote debugger

Any thoughts and ideas are welcome .

Comment: Adobe provides a content debugger which allows you to step through code.  A step through debugger is included as part of the Flex SDK and works great with Flash Builder. I believe other IDEs, such as IntelliJ have support also.

Comment: true, but none of these seem to connect to an swf running in flash pro, which doesn't seem to allow for debugging, connecting to a socket is allowed though...

Comment: I did some searching and came across this: stackoverflow.com/questions/14966589/debugging-flash-swf-panel#comment21014380_14966589 which sounds like what you're looking for.  Is there a reason this doesn't work?

Comment: this leads me back to this question, are you sure you placed the right url?

Comment: I definitely copy and pasted the wrong URL, my mistake I apologize.  Try this: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html or this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_as3_debugging.html

Comment: this is very informative, but it doesn't address debugging swf panel in the flash IDE. as far as i can tell the debugger on it is disabled. unless i find some why to step debug manually or trigger the swf panel debug mode manually(right click and click on debugger doesn't do anything)

Comment: If you right click on the loaded SWF and do not see a "Debugger" option that means your browser does not have the debug version of Flash Player installed; and that is probably the root of your problem.

Comment: im not running it in the browser, im running in the flash IDE, as a swf panel extension. oddly enough when a perform a test on it using Capabilities.isDebugger it prints out true, tracing is also enabled.